# loop and array receive datas from database

Tags: php

I recovered some information from my database and then I turn into the array using:

```
<?php $clients = explode(",",$data['comptes']) ; ?>

<?php $clients = explode(",",$data['comptes']) ;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $clients ); $i++ ) { 
 echo '<option value="'.trim($clients[$i]).',">'.trim($clients[$i]).'</option>'; 
} ?>
```

I would then display all in a selection list.

Before the whole table is not empty, it displays a `print_r()`:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1566 
    [1] => 1599 
    [2] =>
)
```

Then for the selection list so I'm doing following code:

but yet it does not return me the last selection list is empty, I do not see where I made ​​my mistake because I have no error messages.

Comment: Your question seems to be a bit all over the place. Have you remembered a starting <select> and finishing </select>. And did you say you'd checked that clients had things in>

Comment: Why do you call `$clients = explode(",",$data['comptes']) ;` twice?

Comment: You shouldn't use `count($clients)` in your `for` loop definition. You're essentially calling that function each time you iterate. Instead, set its value to a variable, and use the variable.

Comment: It's very likely @PippaRoseSmith is right. Most browsers don't render _orphan_ option elements

Comment: I did not called twice someone of staff edi my post. first I show how I get datas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $clients = explode(",",$data['comptes']) ;

    echo '<select id="selectboxname" name="selectboxname">';

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $clients ) - 1; $i++ ) 
    { 
        echo '<option value="'.trim($clients[$i]).',">'.trim($clients[$i]).'</option>'; 
    } 

    echo '</select>';
?>
```

Make sure you have

```
<select> </select>
```

round your options.

Comment: this code display to me that

<select><option value=","></option></select>

Comment: yes I have select /select in fact the entirely code I use is the following: <select name="selection[]" size="15" id="selection" multiple class="multiple" OnDblClick="javascript:selection_champs(this.form.selection,this.form.liste_champs);listbox_selectall('selection', true);"><?php $clients = explode(",", trim($data['comptes'], ','));
   for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $clients ); $i++ ) 
    { 
        echo '<option value="'.trim($clients[$i]).',">'.trim($clients[$i]).'</option>'; 
    } 
 ?>
    </select>

Comment: Array position 2 doesn't seem to have a value in it. Should it have? And can you post what $data['comptes'] is? If you have put a , at the end of the string, it might be creating a final array position

Comment: it is because of the extra coma, I've change this now there is no more second position in aray for rhis code

Comment: Excellent, glad you sorted it :)

Comment: thanks. But I still don't know how to make this select works, actually even without the extra coma, it give me the same result

Comment: Ah, I think you need count($clients) - 1? In the for loop

Comment: I have this code    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $clients ); $i++ )    Is it enough?

Comment: for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $clients) - 1; $i++ )

Comment: Using that code it give me an empty select <select name="selection[]" size="15" id="selection" multiple="" class="multiple" ondblclick="javascript:selection_champs(this.form.selection,this.form.liste_champs);listbox_selectall('selection', true);">    </select>

Comment: I'm not sure then, I'm afraid. I suggest running through the array in a for loop and just trying to print the values (echo $client[$count]) to check they are definitely in the array. If they arn't displaying in the select box then they are either not in the array or being lost somehow (maybe loss the trim?)

Comment: The problem was with a previous query which used the same var names the thing is date the end of the loop was after the select even if I had one result it has just display one select so I though all was correct. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I am really guessing, but you probably have an extra comma in `$data['comptes']`. Try

```
$clients = explode(",", trim($data['comptes'], ','));
```

Comment: I've changed the code for this it still does not work I have no error messages